Kalman filters which only update a subset of variables?
What is the general approach to updating a subset of variables with a kalman filter?
IE sensor X only updates variable Y.
What I'm a little bit confused on is how the covariance would be propagated.

I cannot conjecture the proper how for this until you edit your question to explain why.  A Kalman filter's behavior is dictated by the system model.  It will only update a subset of the state variables if it is sensible to do so.  I suspect you're doing something wrong -- tell us what you're doing, and we'll help.

As a concrete example, suppose we have a GPS system that only measures one axis.

A much better question to ask is "How can I determine if my Kalman filter can update all of its state variables?"  (Answer: the system whose states you're measuring is observable.)  Then you can concoct whatever system you want, and test it.
